# Codeigniter can't read file name of uploaded file

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Trying to read the file name of a file that is uploaded as part of a form. The print_r command that I'm using to test just shows a blank screen. I have read the manual (near the bottom [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)) pertaining to this and don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Controller:

```
public function do_upload() { 
     $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|txt|pdf|xlsx|csv|xls|bmp'; 
     $config['max_size']      = 1000; 

     $this->load->library('upload', $config);    
     $file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name'); 

     print_r($file_name);
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Corpmuns/do_upload', array('method' => 'post'));?> 

... // some drop-down menus and text fields here

<INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="userfile" id="userfile" > 

</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I corrected your controller in my answer. check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do the upload action so the file was not uploaded yet. That's why you can't get the uploaded file's name. Because it does not exists.
Code `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` and make sure the file is uploaded successfully before you get the filename.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. How can I also rename it? If I try to config['file_name'] with a new name, then $file_name = $this->upload->data('orig_name'); shows me the new name. I want the original name and to rename it.

Comment: @David try `$this->upload->data('client_name')`

Answer (score 0):

Call `do_upload` function from upload library.

**Update Controller:**

```
public function do_upload() { 
     $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|txt|pdf|xlsx|csv|xls|bmp'; 
     $config['max_size']      = 1000; 

     $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
     if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) { //use this function

        $data['error'] = false;
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $data['data'] = $upload_data;
        $data['msg'] = 'Image Successfully Uploaded.';

     } else {

        $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors('', '<br>');

     }

     print_r($data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('input_name'))
        {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {

            $file=$this->upload->data();

            echo $image=$file['file_name'];//Set file name to varilable


        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
name="uploadfile">
```

you should add enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: `form_open_multipart()` creates a form tag with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`